# Certbot SSL renew give me an error message

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

I've an automatic renew for my SSL cert via CertBot.

Today, I've a error when I executed `sudo certbot renew --dry-run`

Here's the message:

```
Attempting to renew cert (domain.ca) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.ca.conf
produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. domain.ca (http-01):
urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client
to verify the domain :: Fetching https://domain.ca.well-known/acme-challenge/OBX6doDYpm-QwzI-1D1Fq5MHm1dTFlG99c4Gy-hLFyw:
Invalid host in redirect target "domain.ca.well-known".
Check webserver config for missing '/' in redirect target.. Skipping.
```

I'm pretty new on this system and I probably miss something here.

Anyone can support me with this please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you checked what the error messages suggests you check?

Comment: You should do exactly what it told you to do: "Check webserver config for missing '/' in redirect target".